# Android Camera setPictureSize

Tags: android, android-camera, resolution

I am developing an android camera application. The device for which I'm developing the app has the following supported Preview sizes in descending order
1920 x 1080
1280 x 720
1088 x 1920
960 x 720
...
And the supported picture sizes are
2592 – 1944
2592 – 1728
2304 – 1296
...
and so on. I am supposed to take the best picture possible from the camera hardware. I have set camera the params as follows

```
 private void setCameraParams(Parameters params) {
        params.set("s3d-prv-frame-layout", "none");
        params.set("s3d-cap-frame-layout", "none");
        params.set("iso", "auto");
        params.set("contrast", 100);
        params.set("brightness", 50);
        params.set("saturation", 100);
        params.set("sharpness", 100);
        params.setAntibanding("auto");
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        params.set("jpeg-quality", 100);
//        params.setJpegQuality(CameraProfile.getJpegEncodingQualityParameter(0, CameraProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        if (params.isZoomSupported())
            params.setZoom(0);
        setPreviewSize(params);
        setPictureSize(params);
        camera.setParameters(params);
    }
```

The methods `setPreviewSize()` and `setPictureSize()` sort the supported sizes in descending order and choose the top one (maximum, best one). Still when I take the picture and pull that file on my system the dimension that I see is `1920 x 1080` which is the same as the `previewSize` that I am setting. The problem is when I take the photo from the default camera and pull the file on my system, the size is `2592 x 1944` which is the max picture size. How can I take a picture from my camera with that size of the image? Any params that need to be added, I have tried with various permutations and combinations of the params but in vain. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Adding code for `setPictureSize() method`

```
private void setPictureSize(Camera.Parameters params) {
        if (sizes == null || resStrings == null) {
            sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            if (sizes != null && !sizes.isEmpty()) {
                Collections.sort(sizes, new Comparator<Camera.Size>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Camera.Size lhs, Camera.Size rhs) {
                        if ((lhs.width > rhs.width) && (lhs.height >= rhs.height))
                            return -1;
                        else if ((rhs.width > lhs.width) && (rhs.height >= lhs.height))
                            return 1;
                        else if ((lhs.width == rhs.width)) {
                            if (lhs.height > rhs.height)
                                return -1;
                            else if (rhs.height > lhs.height)
                                return 1;
                            else
                                return 0;
                        } else
                            return 0;
                    }
                });

                int i = 0;
                resStrings = new String[sizes.size()];
                for (Camera.Size temp : sizes) {
                    resStrings[i] = temp.width + " x " + temp.height;
                    i++;
                    Log.d("PICRES", temp.width + " x " + temp.height);
                }

                params.setPictureSize(sizes.get(getCameraResAtPosition(cameraResSelected)).width,
                        sizes.get(getCameraResAtPosition(cameraResSelected)).height);
            }
        } else {
            params.setPictureSize(sizes.get(getCameraResAtPosition(cameraResSelected)).width,
                    sizes.get(getCameraResAtPosition(cameraResSelected)).height);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
List<Size> sizes = param.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
        if (sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
            size = sizes.get(i);
    }

    param.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
```

it will give the maximum picture size available.

Comment: I have already done this as mentioned "The methods setPreviewSize() and setPictureSize() sort the supported sizes in descending order and choose the top one (maximum, best one)"

Comment: Well I am getting the max size using this piece of code.Try giving some static width and height and see whether it generates the same size or not.

Comment: We cannot give any static value, we have to choose from the list of supported sizes. Whatever size I give for the preview size, the image is taking that size, rather than taking the picture size!

Comment: This is an old question. But for future readers, the above code definitely works. We had some problems with the hardware firmware due to which the params were not set properly.